# Why binded List<string> to ListView textboxes doesn't save changes, despite twoway mode

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, two-way-binding

I have a listview like below (just erased margins, widths etc):

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.PossibleClientsDescriptions, ElementName=projectsListView}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="clients">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I tried many things like:

- just . instead of "Path=."
- UpdateSourceTrigger
- BindsDirectlyToSource
- AsyncState.

PossibleClientsDescriptions is defined in the model like below:

```
    public List<string> PossibleClientsDescriptions { get; set; }
```

The data in the model is displayed in textboxes properly (each string in new row).

But when I edit any of the string in the textbox and refresh the UI, then the changes are lost.

My questions is why PossibleClientsDescriptions doesn't work same way? Why changed string doesn't reflect changes in the model?

Similar situation is working like this (and all the other UI, for example properties of complex classes are saved):

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Tags, ElementName=projectsListView, Converter={StaticResource ListOfStringsToStringConverter}}"/>
```

Where ListOfStringsToStringConverter just merge strings in the list into one whole string and cut it by semicolon for the other way and the property is similar:

```
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }*
```

Comment: Please do not scream at us (whole sentences in capital or bold is screaming)

Comment: Man, I didn't thought anything like this. I am a pieceful and person always. I am sorry anyone who get offended by one whole sentence being bolded. I wanted to show somehow the most important sentence containing the question hoping this would make my post more readable. After your edit all text seems to be with same importance. Maybe you can let me know how can I make my posts being more answered?

Comment: `Path=.` won't work with a two-way binding. The Binding will not magically replace a string element in the source collection. You need to use a wrapper object with a string property.

Comment: @Clemens thank you very much. I thought this as the last way to go, as this is a bit of overworked solution in my opinion, as often simple things in WPF, however possibilities are awesome in this framework. Thank you for teh answer and have a nice day!